# Vertex Multi-labeling on a Graph Network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

We can have this Graph:

```
v = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
10 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
9 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
6 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4};
g = Graph[v, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.5]
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

How can I add other characteristics inside the vertex labels?Such as other numbers in second line of labels?Or more info such as some codes in third line?

Comment: I would suggest to change the title: the title talks about `VertexStyle` while the question deals with `VertexLabel`. Or am I wrong

Comment: @Öskå Both could be.Thanks for the offer but still I prefer to stand on my first title

Comment: This is really a question about vertices with multi-labels and it is a very common thing in network graphs. @Pinguin Dirk I would like to see a few more answers, if possible, with GraphPlot and VertexRenderingFunction. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure there must be an easier way (I cannot see at the moment), but it is possible to use `VertexLabels` the way you want:

```
labs = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
g = Graph[v, 
       VertexLabels -> (With[{vtx = Range@VertexCount@Graph@v}, 
          Rule @@@ Transpose[{vtx, Placed[ToString@# <> "\n" <> labs[[#]] "\nsome text", 
          Center] & /@ vtx}]]),
       VertexStyle -> White,
       VertexSize -> 0.75]
```

So, I just count the vertices (`vtx`) and set up a `Rule` to format the labels. Note that I used `labs` as to show how we can use labels that change from vertex to vertex. I hope this is what you had in mind:

[image]

Also, you might want to look into `GraphPlot`, and into `VertexRenderingFunction` in particular.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Labeled`.  Because 2 of the 3 elements are placed outside the vertex, you can use smaller vertices.

```
Graph[{ Labeled[1, Placed[{1, "New York", "USA"}, {Center, Above, Below}]], 
        Labeled[2, Placed[{2, "Paris", "France"}, {Center, Above, Below}]], 
        Labeled[3, Placed[{3, "Rome", "Italy"}, {Center, Above, Below}]]}, 
      {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
 VertexLabelStyle -> 14, VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.1, ImagePadding -> 30]
```

[image: VertexLabels]

Comment: Are you on _Mathematica_ 9?

Comment: Yes. I'm on Mathemaica 9. But `Labeled` does not required 9.

Comment: I know. But I was wondering why your `Graph` started on the bottom left while mine started on the right :) So I guess it's some versions differences.

Comment: On my machine, your code places the vertices in the same positions as my code. So, if you are using v 9, I can't explain the discrepancy.

Comment: And on mine, your code places the vertices on the same positions as mine ;-) Hence the version question.

Comment: More precisely, I have Mathematica v 9.0.1.0 running on OS X 10.8.5

Comment: I was just asking that because I was wondering whether there is a way to decide where to start or not. And apparently it has been changed between the two versions.

Comment: Try entering the vertex names in a different order.  E.g. `Graph[{2, 3, 1}...`

Comment: I was more likely thinking about changing starting point in functions like `GridGraph`.

Comment: Compare `GridGraph[{2, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]` with 
`GridGraph[{2, 3}, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[(r = Range[6]) -> RotateLeft[r, 3]], 
 ImagePadding -> 10]`.

Comment: By doing that you only change their `Labels` but not the way they are created. But the idea is here I guess :)

Comment: Yes. If you want finer control over where the nodes are placed, you'd need to fiddle with GraphLayout or the vertex coordinates themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Quite similar to Pinguin Dirk's answer, but here it is:

```
v = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
     1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
     10 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     9 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
     8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
     6 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4};

vertexLabels = Table[n -> Placed[Column[{n, "foo"}, Center], Center],
  {n, VertexCount[Graph[v]]}];

g = Graph[v, VertexLabels -> vertexLabels, VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with your answer & Pinguin Dirk's is that the OP would not really be able to say anything else than `foo` or `some text`. Plus, the OP would not be able to choose whether he wants more than one line or not.